# Search API Usage

Tags: 8, search

I'm new to search api. Can anyone please make me understand about the usage of "Search API" on my opinion below.

As far my understanding, it can index from multiple source like solr, mongodb or any other source that defined in service (as it allowed me to configure multiple server) and can serve search result by combining all the data.

OR

It provide a mechanism to index existing data through configured server?

Answer (score 1):

Search API is a module the creates index where are indexed nodes or other entities.

If you want to use it you have to have a "server" (by default the index is the same db of the drupal installation). There are modules that implements connection between search api and server (Solr, Elastic Search, for example).

After you have configured the index you can use Views to build view with data from the search api index and also use facet integration.

Comment: can you explain more please. so can I gather as many source as i like together combined? for example i have three sister site there are using different server. can i combine all of their search result into my site? if they share search data in xml format or json format?